# What’s the difference between a power supply, a buck converter and a step-up booster?

Tags: power-supply

Do these words mean very specific things? Are they all the same? What are the defining factors?

Comment: What has your research told you so far? Have you tried to learn about these terms through the usual internet resources?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question that has shown zero research effort as a quick Google search of each component will easily answer the question

Comment: I googled the question and landed here. The answer was useful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A buck converter is a circuit that reduces an input voltage to a lower voltage with a higher current capacity.

A boost converter or step-up booster increases an input voltage to a higher voltage with a lower current capacity.

Those two terms are circuit descriptions and may be parts of more complex equipment including power supplies. However they be applied as a shorter version of something like "boost converter power supply"

A power supply is a product or circuit that receives input power at a voltage that may not be well regulated and delivers power at a voltage or current that is usually well regulated. If the output is not regulated the term unregulated power supply is usually applied. A power supply may be adjustable and often has protective features such as current limit for a voltage supply and voltage limit for a current supply. It may have fuses, a circuit breaker, over-temperature protection. Power supply products may have connectors of a type that would not be used if they were built into a product. A power supply in its own inclosure would usually be called a workbench power supply, but that is usually shortened to bench supply or just power supply.

Answer (score 1):

A buck converter takes a voltage and outputs a lower voltage.  A step-up booster takes a voltage and outputs a higher voltage.  A power supply is a more generic term for either of these.

Comment: So buck converter == step-down converter?

Comment: @user1282931 a buck converter is one kind of step-down converter.

Comment: All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares.  Or in this case, all buck converters are step-down converters, but not all step-down converters are buck converters.  :-)